# Does "sync -f /home" apply to /home or /?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Suppose that `/home` is a different filesystem than `/`, and I do `sync -f /home`.  According to `man sync`:

```
   -f, --file-system
          sync the file systems that contain the files
```

So would that mean that `/home` is sync'd, or that `/` is sync'd?

Comment: While I don't know the answer to your question, if you want to be sure to sync the `/home` filesystem you can specify `/home/.` -- which exists on any POSIX system.